# Calculating moving average for every 5 seconds in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to calculate moving average for my data in MongoDB. My data structure is as below

```
{
    "_id" : NUUID("54ab1171-9c72-57bc-ba20-0a06b4f858b3"),    
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2018-05-30T21:31:05.957Z"),
    "Type" : 3,
    "Value" : NumberDecimal("15.905414991993847")
}
```

I want to calculate the average of values for each type within 2 days and for each 5 seconds. In this case I put Type in `$match` pipeline but I prefer to group the result by `Type` and separate the result by `Type`. Something I did is as below

```
var start = new Date("2018-05-30T21:31:05.957Z");
var end = new Date("2018-06-01T21:31:05.957Z");
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 34560; i++) {               
   start.setSeconds(start.getSeconds() + 5);
   if (start <= end)
   { 
    var a = new Date(start);
    arr.push(a);   
   }
}

db.Data.aggregate([
{$match:{"DateTime":{$gte:new Date("2018-05-30T21:31:05.957Z"), 
          $lte:new Date("2018-06-01T21:31:05.957Z")}, "Type":3}},
{$bucket: {
      groupBy: "$DateTime",
      boundaries: arr,
      default: "Other",
      output: {
        "count": { $sum: 1 },
        "Value": {$avg:"$Value"}
      }
    }
}
])
```

It seems, it is working but the performance is too slow. How can I make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the behavior you describe with 2 days worth of 1 second observations in the DB and a `$match` that pulls just one day's worth.  The agg works "fine" if you bucket by, say, 60 seconds.  But 15 seconds took 6 times as long, to 30 seconds.  And every 5 seconds?  144 seconds.   5 seconds yields an array of 17280 buckets.  Yep.

So I went client-side and dragged all 43200 docs to the client and created a naive linear search bucket slot finder and calc in javascript.

```
c=db.foo.aggregate([
{$match:{"date":{$gte:new Date(osv), $lte:new Date(endv) }}}
                ]);

c.forEach(function(r) {
    var x = findSlot(arr, r['date']);

    if(buckets[x] == undefined) {
        buckets[x] = {lb: arr[x], ub: arr[x+1], n: 0, v:0};
    }
    var zz = buckets[x];
    zz['n']++;
    zz['v'] += r['val'];
});
```

This actually worked somewhat faster but same order of performance, about 92 seconds.

Next, I changed the linear search in `findSlot` to a bisection search.   The 5 second bucket went from 144 seconds to **.750 seconds: almost 200x faster.**   This includes dragging the 43200 records and running the `forEach` and bucketing logic above.  So it stands to reason that `$bucket` may not be using a great algo and suffers when the bucket array is more than a couple hundred long.

Acknowledging this, we can instead make use of `$floor` of the delta between the start time and the observation time to bucket the data:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match:{"date":{$gte:now, $lte:new Date(endv) }}}

    // Bucket by turning offset from "now" into floor divided by the number           
    // of seconds of grouping.  In this way, the resulting number becomes the         
    // slot into the virtual buckets, e.g.:                                           
    // date            now            diff/1000   floor @ 5 seconds:                  
    // 1514764800000   1514764800000  0           0                                   
    // 1514764802000   1514764800000  2           0                                   
    // 1514764804000   1514764800000  4           0                                   
    // 1514764806000   1514764800000  6           1                                   
    // 1514764808000   1514764800000  8           1                                   
    // 1514764810000   1514764800000  10          2                                   
    ,{$addFields: {"ff": {$floor: {$divide: [ {$divide: [ {$subtract: [ "$date", now ]}, 1000.0 ]}, secondsBucket ] }} }}

    // Now just group by the numeric slot number!
    ,{$group: {_id: "$ff", n: {$sum:1}, tot: {$sum: "$val"}, avg: {$avg: "$val"}} }

    // Get it in 0-n order....                                                        
    ,{$sort: {_id: 1}}
                ]);

    found 17280 in 204 millis
```

So we now have a server-side solution that is just .204 seconds, or 700x faster.  And you don't have to sort the input because `$group` will take care of bundling the slot numbers.  And the `$sort` after the `$group` is optional (but sort of handy...)